# JavaScript slideshow error, TypeError, cannot set property

Tags: javascript, slideshow, typeerror

got an issue with this JS that I found here, and I haven't found the answer. Chrome throws an error through the console that says 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined' in reference to line 14. I've tried all the solutions I've found on here with no joy.

```
 var image1=new Image()
image1.src="Images/1.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="Images/2.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="Images/3.jpg"


var step=1
function slideit(){

    if (!document.images)
        return
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
    if (step<3)
        step++
    else
        step=1

    setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
slideit()
```

Comment: what is `document.images.slide`? it's probably undefined

Comment: Slide is the name of the img tag where I want the images to appear.

Comment: please add your html and code for initiating `document.images` also

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-slides.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>
<p><img src="../logo.jpg" width="283" height="83" alt=""/></p>
<img src="Images/1.jpg" name="slide"  width="100%" height="368"/>

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're not using `getElementById()` to set src on Image?

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit better? I'm very new to JS. I know what it is, but where do I need to use it?

Comment: @user3822332 Your best bet is to google `getElementById()`. Its a good way to get a reference to an element in your markup which you can then change properties on. You're on the right track :-)